# statistical prediction - how to measure degree of overestimation separately with degree of underestimation

Tags: python, statsmodels

i am using python to perform prediction forecast with various models and wanted to measure how well is the prediction. i have use MAE, MSE, RMSE, Chi2, pvalues to compare models, which can show goodness of fit.
however, i am unable to find a method to measure model's degree of over-estimation (e.g. forecasted value has more values under the actual value by X) or under-estimation (e.g. forecast has more values over the actual values by X).

Comment: You can always create one. Creating these statistics are pretty easy to do. Just compare each number and subtract in loop.

Comment: I tend to create my own statistical error algorithms for prediction algorithms but I usually find that all that effort was kind of wasted and RMSE is the best. However, this is not always the case. Sometimes custom error algorithms are the way to go.